# Резрешить путь к файлу без кавычек - Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-cli

При сборке проекта (Vue-cli 3), ругается Webpack 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Залез в исходники, и вижу, что из-за странного синтаксиса, Webpack не разрешить путь к картинке, которая лежит рядом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой плагин или какие настройик могут помочь Webpack'у разрешить этот путь и найти картинку?

Comment: А при чём тут кавычки? Ну и [mcve] в студию, гадать по скриншотам умеют не только лишь все

Comment: @andreymal, я решил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, нужный мне плагин называется css-loader, https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader. Для того, чтобы Webpack правильно разрешал пути, в опциях к этому плагину необходимо передать параметр `url:true`. Для проекта созданного через `vue-cli v.3` это делается так, файл `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        url: true,
      },
    },
  },
```